# find the common ids between two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

have the following data frames:

```
id1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
spent<-c(10,20,30,40,50)
id2<-c(1,3,4)
x<-c(1,2,2)
df1<-data.frame(id1,spent)
df2<-data.frame(id2,x)
```

I need to find the ids in `df1` which also exist in `df2` and export all their information to a new data frame (let's say `df3`). on this basis `df3` should look as follow:

```
   id1     spent
   1         10
   3         30
   4         40
```

I would be thankful if you could help me with this problem.

Comment: -1 duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297237/merging-two-data-frames-in-r-that-have-common-and-uncommon-samples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `merge` see `?merge` for get information about `by.x` and `by.y` arguments

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x="id1", by.y="id2")[,-3] # this is the desired output you showed
  id1 spent
1   1    10
2   3    30
3   4    40

merge(df1, df2, by.x="id1", by.y="id2") # this is with "all their information"
  id1 spent x
1   1    10 1
2   3    30 2
3   4    40 2
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `data.table` package, which might be faster than using `merge` if you're merging a lot of IDs. For example,

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(id1, spent, key = "id1")

dt1[J(unique(df2$id2))]
#    id1 spent
# 1:   1    10
# 2:   3    30
# 3:   4    40
```

n.b. The `unique` also probably isn't necessary, but I included it in case the real data include duplicate `id2`s.

**EDIT** The `J()` is necessary, plus see the comment by Matthew Dowle.

Comment: The `J()` *is* necessary, otherwise it would lookup by row number rather than the column contents. `J()` (or `.()` etc) is only optional on `character` input, but needed for `numeric`.  Might be easier to point people to use `merge()`, but use `merge()` on `data.table` for the speed. That can maybe introduce `data.table` more easily than needing to learn `J()` etc. The `merge.data.table` method is a lot faster in v1.8.0+ than it used to be, as fast as `X[Y]` in many cases.