# R: merging two data frames with common and uncommon elements for non-unique keys

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames with some common and some uncommon elements.
Example:

```
x <- data.frame(name=c("a","a","a","a"), dep=c("s","k","m","n"), stringsAsFactors = F)
y <- data.frame(name=c("a","a","a","a"), dep=c("v","k","i","m"), stringsAsFactors = F)
> x
  name dep
1    a   s
2    a   k
3    a   m
4    a   n
> y
  name dep
1    a   v
2    a   k
3    a   i
4    a   m
```

I want to merge these two data frames by the "name" column to get a result like:

```
> z
  name dep.x dep.y
1    a     s  <NA>
2    a     n  <NA>
3    a     k     k
4    a     m     m
5    a  <NA>     v
6    a  <NA>     i
```

I tried merging the two data frames with `all=TRUE` option, but what I'm getting is all possible combinations and no rows with NA.

```
> merge(x,y, by="name", all=T)
   name dep.x dep.y
1     a     s     v
2     a     s     k
3     a     s     i
4     a     s     m
5     a     k     v
6     a     k     k
7     a     k     i
8     a     k     m
9     a     m     v
10    a     m     k
11    a     m     i
12    a     m     m
13    a     n     v
14    a     n     k
15    a     n     i
16    a     n     m
```

How do I get the result I want?

P.S. My question is somewhat similar to 
[Merging two data frames in R that have common and uncommon samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297237/merging-two-data-frames-in-r-that-have-common-and-uncommon-samples)

except, a) I don't have an "ID" column to merge on, b) the result he was getting but didn't want is the the result I want.

Comment: This really isn't a traditional merge. If you do something like `merge(cbind(x, x=T), cbind(y, y=T), all = TRUE)` you get closer to your desired output but we just add additional columns to track presence in each of the data.frames.

Comment: To @MrFlick's code, add `%>% mutate_at(vars(x,y), funs(dep[.]))` and you're closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
merge(cbind(x,dep.x=x$dep),cbind(y,dep.y=y$dep),all=T)[-2]
  name dep.x dep.y
1    a  <NA>     i
2    a     k     k
3    a     m     m
4    a     n  <NA>
5    a     s  <NA>
6    a  <NA>     v
```